# Empty array returns true? Given an array of ints, return true if every element is a 1 or a 4

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

> ```
> Given an array of ints, return true if every element is a 1 or a 4.
>
> only14([1, 4, 1, 4]) → true
> only14([1, 4, 2, 4]) → false
> only14([1, 1]) → true
> ```

I came up with the following algorithm which returns all the expected answers, EXCEPT for an empty array which should return `true`:

```
public boolean only14(int[] nums) {

  boolean flag = false;

  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

    if (nums[i] == 1 || nums[i] == 4) {
      flag = true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return flag;
}
```

From the solutions, the following input should yield `true`, but I can't figure out why:

`only14([]) → true`

I understand the default value is 0, so what am I missing such that I should expect the return value of the boolean to be `true`?

Comment: Get rid of `flag`, and just return `true` at the end.

Comment: Because the empty set contains no numbers that are not 1 or 4.

Comment: I understand that you are not asking about how you can write code that would return true for empty set. Instead, you are asking about why true should be returned for empty set. If that is the case, please read this article about material conditional operator [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional). The first paragraph would be enough.

Comment: @Haozhun That is exactly right, and thank you for the link. This is a rather embarrassing gap in my knowledge which I'm glad you spotted!

Answer (score 3):

The following should work. It returns `true` unless there are any values that are not 1 or 4.

```
public boolean only14(int[] nums) {
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    int val = nums[i];
    if (val != 1 && val != 4) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The empty set contains no values that aren't `1` or `4`, so it should be `true`. I would prefer a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) like

```
public boolean only14(int[] nums) {
    for (int n : nums) {        // for each int n in nums
        if (n == 1 || n == 4) { // if it is 1 or 4 keep looping
            continue;
        }
        return false;           // it isn't 1 or 4, return false
    }
    return true;                // every value is 1 or 4.
}
```

In Java 8+, you could implement it with an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) like

```
public boolean only14(int[] nums) {
    return IntStream.of(nums).allMatch(x -> x == 1 || x == 4);
}
```

Comment: A much simpler and more elegant algorithm. Also, the explanation is much clearer to me now. I misinterpreted the instructions - I thought it was looking for array that must contain either 1's or 4's, as opposed to an array that simply does not contain alternate values. An interesting difference (to me, at least).

Comment: Any reason you stuck with the positive condition instead of `if (n != 1 && n != 4) return false;`?

Comment: @shmosel As an alternative to cybersam's answer. Both work here. I personally think it's more readable this way.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine:-

```
public boolean only14(int[] nums) {
  for(int i=0;i<=nums.length-1;i++){
     if (nums[i]!= 1 && nums[i]!= 4){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```